# Waiting for API call before proceeding to display component

Tags: vue.js, callback, axios

I am using axios to make an API call. The call occurs when the mouse enters certain HTML elements on the page. Usually, on the first hover none of the data is received, but on the second one the data usually appears. I figure that this is because I am not waiting for the API call to return. Is there a way to implement this?

Below is the Axios instance that I use to make the API call.

Thank you for the time and consideration.

```
instance
.get('observations?patientId=37')
.then((response) => {
   this.clinicaltabs[0].title = response.data.data;
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more of code so we can try to figure out what we could improve ? For the moment, I don't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do:

Use a spinner loading for you hoverable HTML element and make it visible when sending your request.

```
this.loading = true; //Some way for disabling the hover event

instance
.get('observations?patientId=37')
.then((response) => {
   this.clinicaltabs[0].title = response.data.data;
})
.finally(() => this.loading = false);
```

Then you could use the `v-if="loading"` or something like to control the display of the component until it loads.